# UUID uniqueness

Tags: random, uuid

I really just want verification as I think this is true.  When I create a UUID I ge
"3dc576a5-5bcc-44e4-b1c7-cbed7d3dcd4c".  What I am using it for cannot contain dashes, so I remove them, "3dc576a55bcc44e4b1c7cbed7d3dcd4c".  This should be unique still, right?  That is, it won't create something like "3dc576a-55bcc4-4e4b1c7-cbed7d3dcd4c" or
"3dc57-6a-55bcc44-e4b1c7-cbed7d3dcd4c" etc, correct?  I suppose even if it did it would be extremely rare.

Comment: Those dashes are just representation format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Textual_representation

Comment: And, by definition they cannot help w.r.t. uniqueness in the field of UUID's as they are always the same character at the same position.

Answer (score 0):

For the UUID `3dc576a5-5bcc-44e4-b1c7-cbed7d3dcd4c` the metadata and the number of random bits are:

```
Version: 4 (Indicates a randomly generated UUID)
Variant: Specified in RFC 4122 (Typically Variant 1 in UUID terminology)
```

Number of Random Bits: 122 bits

---

A UUID is typically represented as 32 hexadecimal characters, divided into 5 groups separated by hyphens. The format is 8-4-4-4-12. In a version 4 UUID, the metadata bits are located as follows:

1. **Version (4 bits):** This is located in the 13th to 16th bits of the UUID. These bits are part of the third group of characters. In hexadecimal representation, it's the first character of the third group (7th character overall). For a version 4 UUID, this character will be '4'.
2. **Variant (2 bits):** These bits are in the 49th to 50th positions. They are found in the first two bits of the 17th character (first character of the fourth group). In a version 4 UUID, the hexadecimal representation of these two bits will be one of 8, 9, A, or B.

So, in the UUID `3dc576a5-5bcc-44e4-b1c7-cbed7d3dcd4c`, the '4' in 'e4' indicates that it's a version 4 UUID, and the 'b' in 'b1c7' is part of the variant encoding. The rest of the characters are randomly generated.

---

The chance of collisions is very low for 122 random bits, as long as those random bits are created using a well seeded RNG that produced well distributed values.